# Confirm email field in Mailchimp with gravity form

Tags: wordpress, plugins, newsletter, mailchimp-api-v3.0, gravityforms

How to create gravity form, to check email address field already exist in Mailchimp list and if the email address is already in the Mailchimp list give a notification message, or if it doesn't  Mailchimp list add some extra fields like address and add this person to the list?

I was thinking of a logic condition in the email field to check  Mailchimp list, if it's already there, but I just can't figure it out.

Here is a sample [link](http://resources.csoonline.com/ccd/assets/137211/detail)

Comment: @kiran.koduru have gravity form have tried but am stuck I was looking how to do it or another plugin to do the same. Do you have any in mind?

Comment: Edit your question to include what you have done so far with gravity forms.

Comment: @kiran.koduru I was able to put allow users to input email to download but I am stuck at giving condition there this site that does what I want. This http://resources.csoonline.com/ccd/assets/137211/detail